# How to cause xfce4 whiskermenu to invoke when super is pressed?

Tags: 12.04, unity, shortcut-keys, xfce, xfce-panel

I have installed Xfce4 Panel and its whisker menu plugin onto my instance of Unity.
 I want to make the whisker menu appear when I press the `super` key instead of Unity Dash.
 How might one go about doing this?
 I haven't found any way to do this in the preferences for the plugin.
 Note that I am running Ubuntu 12.04.
Why didn't I just install XFCE? Because I'm lazy, I like to mix-and-match good software to see if I like the outcome and am I running Ubuntu on a Chromebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whiskermenu has the `xfce4-popup-whiskermenu` command.
Whiskermenu will pop up when you run this command.
(I don't know how to assign a shortcut to the command in Unity.)